# Attempted to assign to readonly property on IOS10 wechat 6

Tags: ionic2, angular2-directives

I tried to run ionic tabs demo on IOS10.3.2 with wechat6.5.10
I started with this command:

```
ionic start myapp tabs
cd ./myapp
ionic serve
```

an error occured :
[image]